# Is it possible to style a child element when hovering over the parent element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to modify the styles of `.childElement` when `.parentElement:hover` is fired.

Something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.parentElement:hover {
  .childElement {
   display:block;
  }
}
</style>
<div class="parentElement">
  <div class="childElement"></div>
</div>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```css
.parentElement:hover .childElement {
  display:block;
}
```

***Note:** CSS does not currently support nesting, however, [it is planned](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-hierarchies/). Currently, the proposed syntax is as follows:*

```css
.parentElement:hover {
  /* Note the ampersand (&) */
  & .childElement {
   display:block;
  }
}
```